# Discord.py - Message, which only one user can see in the server

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I'm making a Discord bot in Python and I want to add a feature, when message can be seen only by one user.
[image]

I made an example from Dank Memer bot. Any ideas?

Comment: Use slash commands, you can hide the answers.

Comment: With slash commands you can hide the prompt as well

Answer (score 4):

These are called `Ephemeral` messages, however, they can only be used in response to an interaction.  Examples of interactions are things like slash commands (like mentioned above), drop-down menus, and buttons.

Unfortunately, the current version of discord.py does not support interactions, so you will have to use a different library.

You can check out some cool libraries for interactions.  I would personally recommend discord-components, but that's just my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

You can now do this, for anyone googling:

```
 await interaction.response.send_message(f"only you, {interaction.user}, can see this!", ephemeral=True)
```